# How to Upgrade to Linuxmint 17.2

Tags: linux, linux-mint, upgrade

In the Linux Mint upgrade manual I found this entry:

> Upgrading to 17.2 is relatively easy:
>
> In the Update Manager, click on the Refresh button to check for any
> new version of mintupdate and mint-upgrade-info. If there are updates
> for these packages, apply them. Launch the System Upgrade by clicking
> on “Edit->Upgrade to Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela”.

[image]

but in the Update Manager I don't have that option

**My update manager Screen Shot:**

[image]

how do I make this option available?

Comment: Do you have the newest version of Update Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way of upgrading Linux Mint is the Update Manager, but there is always the lesser known alternative, using the command line. To do so open a terminal and type:
`sudo cp -v /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list.bak`
Press [ENTER] and then type your password when prompted. Then replace your Qiana sources with Rebecca sources:
`sudo sed -i 's/qiana/rebecca/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list`
Then update your repository list with `sudo apt-get update`. It should not take over 2-3 minutes. Then perform the actual upgrade with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. This should take a while (It could take a *VERY* long time if you have slower hardware). When it is finished updating, reboot your computer, and you should be running 17.2 Rafaela.

#### A note of Caution

Although the correct way of upgrading from the command line, this method is not without risk, and it sometimes fails. As the old saying goes, *"If it ain't broke, don't fix it"*. This applies here as well. If Qiana is working fine and there is no actual need for an OS upgrade, then stick with what works. If you are curious(which is a good thing), then you can go ahead and follow these instructions carefully, although I highly recommend making either a full backup of your computer, or at least moving all your important files and documents into a directory and ZIPing it... If you are upgrading because there is an important bug fix or feature in the new update, then by all means, go ahead and update - just be careful.
For more information on upgrading to Rafaela, go to [this page](http://linuxmint.com/rel_rafaela_cinnamon.php). 
Regards,
*Interesting...*